# Javascript object collision

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

I have a simple javascript program.

You can move a square in it.

If the square conflicts with an object, a pixel will jump back.

It works.
But it will not work if two objects are next to each other.
Example for this code. if the square y coordinate is 200 and is close to silver then it does not collide.

How can I solve it?

How can I solve it?
If someone could have a simpler solution, then thank you.

```html
<body onload="Start()">
  <script>
    function Start() {
      myAvatar = new component("black", 30, 30, 50, 50);
      components = {
        silverMine: new component("grey", 30, 30, 300, 170),
        forest: new component("green", 30, 30, 300, 200),
      }
      Field.start();
    }

    var Field = {
      field: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.field.height = 800;
        this.field.width = 800;
        this.context = this.field.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.field, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(fieldUpdate, 10);

        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          Field.keys = Field.keys || [];
          Field.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })

        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
          Field.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
      },

      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.field.width, this.field.height);
      }
    }

    function component(color, width, height, x, y) {
      this.color = color;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;

      this.componentUpdate = function() {
        ctx = Field.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    }

    function collision(a) {
      for (var prop in components) {
        c = components[prop];
        com = prop;

        if ((a.x == c.x - c.width) && (a.y >= c.y - c.width && a.y <= c.y - c.width + 60)) {
          console.log("balról");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.x == c.x + c.width) && (a.y >= c.y - c.width && a.y <= c.y - c.width + 60)) {
          console.log("jobbrol");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.y == c.y - c.width) && (a.x >= c.x - c.width && a.x <= c.x - c.width + 60)) {
          console.log("felülröl");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.y == c.y + c.width) && (a.x >= c.x - c.width && a.x <= c.x - c.width + 60)) {
          console.log("alulrol");
          return true;
        }

        if ((a.x == c.x - c.width + 1) && (a.y >= c.y - c.width && a.y <= c.y - c.width + 60)) {
          a.x = c.x - c.width;
          console.log("5");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.x == c.x + c.width - 1) && (a.y >= c.y - c.width && a.y <= c.y - c.width + 60)) {
          a.x = c.x + c.width;
          console.log("6");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.y == c.y - c.width + 1) && (a.x >= c.x - c.width && a.x <= c.x - c.width + 60)) {
          a.y = c.y - c.width;
          console.log("7");
          return true;
        }
        if ((a.y == c.y + c.width - 1) && (a.x >= c.x - c.width && a.x <= c.x - c.width + 60)) {
          a.y = c.y + c.width;
          console.log("8");
          return true;
        }

      }

      return false;
    }

    function fieldUpdate() {
      Field.clear();
      if (Field.keys && Field.keys[37]) {
        myAvatar.x--;
      }
      if (Field.keys && Field.keys[38]) {
        myAvatar.y--;
      }
      if (Field.keys && Field.keys[39]) {
        myAvatar.x++;
      }
      if (Field.keys && Field.keys[40]) {
        myAvatar.y++;
      }
      collision(myAvatar);
      myAvatar.componentUpdate();
      for (var prop in components) {
        components[prop].componentUpdate();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are able to move in the x and y direction at the same time as you have an off by 1 type of error with some of the detection. Therefore, when you are one pixel below the bottom of the top square it actually detects a collision in the y direction with that square and only stops y from moving but allows the x move.

Here is a change that doesn't allow collisions although it does get "stuck" in places:

```
function fieldUpdate() {
  Field.clear();
  var oldX = myAvatar.x;
  var oldY = myAvatar.y;
  if (Field.keys && Field.keys[37]) {
    myAvatar.x--;
  }

  if (Field.keys && Field.keys[39]) {
    myAvatar.x++;
  }

  if (collision(myAvatar)) {
    myAvatar.x = oldX;
    myAvatar.y = oldY;
  }

  var oldX = myAvatar.x;
  var oldY = myAvatar.y;

  if (Field.keys && Field.keys[40]) {
    myAvatar.y++;
  }      

  if (Field.keys && Field.keys[38]) {
    myAvatar.y--;
  }

  if (collision(myAvatar)) {
    myAvatar.x = oldX;
    myAvatar.y = oldY;
  }

  myAvatar.componentUpdate();
  for (var prop in components) {
    components[prop].componentUpdate();
  }
}
```

If you fix your off by 1 errors, it should also not get stuck.

Also another issue is that you have `c.y - c.width` in a couple of places. These should likely by `c.y - c.height`. This is going to be a problem if you ever make non-square shapes.

Comment: Thanks, but it will never be true the collision(myAvatar).

Comment: So as long as it is in collision, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you return in the collision loop, resulting that only one object gets detected per movement. That would be fine if all movements were stopped / reversed but reversing only one direction allows the other to roam freely through anything else.

A way to fix that would be to remove all returns in that function.
Additionally watch that video "[Bounding Box Collision Detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b_reDI7iPM)" to fix your algorithm because currently it ignores the width and height of your own avatar.